# datagrid view select from the list and search from the textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

In my datagridview, i got 4 columns and a textbox to search. I have loaded 4 col names in the combo-box list when the user choose the column name and type something in the textbox, 
I want to pointout the row in the datagird and display it to the display model.

I have function DisplaySelectedProjection, when the user choose any row i the datagirdview the values of the selected row displayed in the textboxes of the corresponding one.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }   

 private void DataGridDepthProjection_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplaySelectedProjection();
    }

    private void DisplaySelectedProjection()
    {
        if (DataGridDepthProjection.CurrentRow == null)
            return;

        var index = DataGridDepthProjection.CurrentRow.Index;
        if (index < 0 || index >= bindingList.Count)
            return;

        var item = bindingList[index];
        var depthProjection = depthProjections[item];

        Display(depthProjection);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the DataGridView rows and cells to match the criteria. For this, you need to use:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{                            
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
         /* Your code here */
    }
}
```

In the DataGridView's RowChanging event, you need to change the color of the cell.

Comment: Please give me some more details.

Comment: What more you want to know? I'm away for an hour.